# Path error when accessing .cshtml file in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have an `asp.net core` 5 application running on Azure App Service, which should fetch a `.cshtml` file that serves as an email template. I use the `.ContentRootPath` attribute of the `IWebHostEnvironment` interface to return the first part of the path, and I concatenate the rest of the path to the file, with a string. Locally, everything works fine, but there is something wrong with fetching the .cshtml file when the application is running in Azure.

When fetching the .cshtml, the following error is observed:

> Could not find a part of the path '/home/site/wwwroot/wwwroot/Templates/Email/EmailRegistroAssinatura.cshtml'

But locally, none of that happens. I expected the .ContentRootPath attribute to return the first part of the path according to the environment where the application was running.

My code is the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

string projectRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
string file = "wwwroot/Templates/Email/" + fileName + ".cshtml";
string path = Path.Combine(projectRootPath, file);

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
{
    htmlStringEmail = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

What to do to get the path correctly, using the same code in both environments?

Comment: have you tried `_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath`?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work either.

Comment: you need absolute path, get `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and then append the relative file path and try

Comment: @viveknuna, I keep getting the same error with GetCurrentDirectory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my test, I found the root cause. The reason is the static files(folder) not include when you deploy it. You can go to kudu site and check it.

1. I face the error message like below.

   [image]
2. I check the static files under wwwroot, and can't find the `Templates` folder, then I add all the folders and file manually like below.

   [image]
3. Then I test again and it works well.

   [image]

**Summary**

1. You can search the official doc about how to include static files when you deploy the project. Or add it manually.
2. Pls not use `.cshtml` file as template, you should use `.html` file, as we know, the contents under wwwroot should be static files. Normally we will create new `.cshtml` files under `Views` folder.